# Javascript Find Nth Digit Number Algorithm Performance

Tags: javascript, node.js, algorithm

I am trying to solve the algorithm here is the desired output

Create a function that show n-th position of a digit and its value.

We have this kind of number:
01234567891011121314151617181920212223…......N

`Test Case:
Input: 0 
Output: 0th is 0
Input: 1 
Output: 1st is 1
Input: 9 
Output: 9th is 9
Input: 10 
Output: 10th is 1
Input: 1000 
Output: 1000th is 3
Input: 1000000 
Output: 100000000th is 1
Input: 1000000000 
Output: 1000000000th is 1`

have done with following code

```js
function findDigit(N){
var digits = "";
for(var i = 0;i <= N;i++){
    digits += ""+i;
    }
     return `value of ${N} is ${digits.charAt(N)}`;
}
console.log(findDigit('1000000000'));
```

But it's very slow. is there is another way to do or refactoring require

Help will be appreciated

Comment: Champernowne constant - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59807897) for an `O(log n)` solution in JS